# CSS background image overflowing over HTML?

Tags: css

My background image, which covers the entire web page, overflows past the HTML and body elements, even though they're both set to 100%.

It's a simple page, [as seen here](http://seocial.ly/fifth/).

I've tried several different techniques to place the background image (including setting it to `cover`, but I still encounter this overflow issue)

(I feel like I'm going a little crazy, but I'm probably missing something that's very apparent).

Comment: please always post the relevant code within the question and add a sandbox example, like in jsFiddle. Anways. Do you mean the first `<img>`in your body tag? This not quite an background-image. When you mean the `.translucent` part, remove the `height:100%;` and use `min-height: 100%` instead.

Comment: I can see your background image is an image in your html, instead a background-image. Any reason in particular?

Comment: I tried the background image as `cover` first, but that presented this issue. I tried technique #2 found here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ as a fix.

Comment: Just reverted it back to the original (background image as cover), where I first encountered this issue.

Comment: have you tried applying the background image to the `.translucent` div instead of `<body>`?

Comment: Thanks, just fixed this by setting translucent's min-height to 100% (rather than just height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After reverting it back to a `cover` background image rather than the standalone image I placed with reduced z-index as a bug fix]

Setting `.translucent`'s `min-height` to 100% (rather than just `height: 100%;`) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try `overflow:hidden`

```
.translucent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 92, 60, 0.95);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: yes, hiding the overflow fixes it, but once this page gets longer (which it will), the user won't be able to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you set this  in the body tag.
It's much easier to give the body tag a background-image.

So i changed your body css style to this:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('cover-plaza-707-fifth-construction.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And you now can delete `<img src="cover-plaza-707-fifth-construction.jpg" id="bg">`

I hope this solves the problem, i haven't tested the scrolling yet.

Comment: This is what I had originally, the faux `<img>` background was an attempted fix. Revered back to what it was before (cover background-image). Same issue, see? http://seocial.ly/fifth/

Comment: it looks fine to me now, i can't see the problem anymore really.

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it by setting my translucent green layer to `min-height:100%` (rather than just height). Thanks for your help!